# Could bioengineered nanobots be used to grow/develop organs and tissue inside the human body?

Tags: biology, science-fiction, biochemistry, nanotechnology

Like the title states, could a bioengineered organ meant to produce specially designed nanobots, be placed into a human body, and once properly activated is capable of developing multiple organs whilst simultaneously radically changing the human body into a trans-human state.

The organ is primarily fueled by the subjects own metabolism, and as such can only produce biomaterial through the consumption of copious amounts of nutrients and proteins.

Maturation of the subject would take place between 5-10 years.

But back to the question, could a specialized nanite swarm be used to develop internal organs within the human body? Or do nanites not work like that?

Comment: (a) if you roll your mouse over the [tag:science-based] and [tag:science-fiction] tags and read their summary, you'll discover they're *mutually exclusive.* Please take the time to read the tag wikis then delete one. (b) It's worth pointing out that "nanobots" is another word for "magic." Of course your nanobots can do what you're asking. You're setting the rules for your magic/nanobots. The real question is whether or not you need to explain why they can do this (I'd advise against that).

Answer (score 3):

In principle yes, however don't forget that something growing inside a body in addition to what is already there it is a tumor, often compromising the functioning of the original body, because there is no unused real estate in a body.

Comment: I presume you mean "there is *no* unused real estate in a body."?

Answer (score 3):

I dont see why not.

We mostly think of the body as static. A collagen cell will just sit in the same spot in the body with the same neighbors until they die and are replaced. The reality is much more complex and absolutely not static.

Cells move around. For fistulas (don’t look that up) they can move aside to create holes to get rid of pus and detritus. They can move to try and close wounds and in some cases even migrate through the body to other places on purpose (although more commonly by accident which is another reason why aggressive tumors are so nasty).

But your purpose is to create specific organs in the body in specific places. So what you need is a cell that can trick surrounding cells to move aside to let it pass, this cell uses the local hormones, cell proteïnes and cell waste material to determine where it is in the body and then plant itself to create its organ.

As an alternative you could create a white blood cell lookalike with virus elements. It can fully move through the body between the cells until it identifies a spot where it wants to create an organ, there it attaches itself to a body where it first inserts something like Destroying Angel, which is a substance that destroys DNA, then inserts its own DNA. To make this easier there are cells which can merge their entire cell core with the DNA inside with that of another cell, meaning you don't need to get your own DNA in the now vacant cell core.

Its not possible today, but the elements required to do it absolutely exist. If they are mutually exclusive if you were to program them into a cell is impossible to tell right now. So it could be possible.